# On Proving a Series Representation for $\log \zeta (s)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

In Section 3.14. of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*, there is a sentence that I could not understand (Blue-underlined sentence in [here](https://imgur.com/a/zJ7WcY7)):

Question 1- How does $$\dfrac{1}{w} \bigg( \log \zeta (w+1) - \log \dfrac{1}{w} \bigg)$$ is regular at $w=0$? Writing $\zeta (z) = \dfrac{1}{z-1} + g(z)$, $g(z)$ being entire, and taking $\lim_{w \to 0}$ does not yield a finite one!

Question 2- How "the last term" is equal to the $\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C \log \dfrac{1}{w} \dfrac{x^w}{w} dw$? The last term is a sum of three integrals: $$\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{-\delta}^{-\rho} \log \zeta (\sigma+1) \dfrac{x^{\sigma}}{\sigma} d \sigma + \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{2 \pi} \log \zeta (\rho e^{i \theta} +1) \dfrac{x^{\rho e^{i \theta}}}{\rho e^{i \theta}} \rho i e^{i \theta} d \theta + \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{-\rho}^{-\delta} \log \zeta (\sigma+1) \dfrac{(x e^{2 \pi i})^{\sigma}}{\sigma} d \sigma$$ and how does this is equal to the mentioned integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Write $\zeta(1+z)=g(z)/z$ where $g(z)$ is entire and $g(0)=1$. Now
   $$\dfrac{1}{w} \bigg( \log \zeta (1+w) - \log \dfrac{1}{w} \bigg)=\dfrac{1}{w} \bigg( \log \frac{g(w)}{w} - \log \dfrac{1}{w} \bigg)=\frac{\log g(w)}{w}$$
   which is regular at $0$ since $g(0)=1$.
2. We have $$\int_C \log \zeta (1+w) \dfrac{x^w}{w} dw=\int_C \dfrac{1}{w} \bigg( \log \zeta (1+w) - \log \dfrac{1}{w} \bigg)x^w dw+\int_C \log \dfrac{1}{w} \dfrac{x^w}{w} dw=\int_C \log \dfrac{1}{w} \dfrac{x^w}{w} dw$$
   where we used $1.$ and Cauchy's theorem in the last equality.